# Shared variables in Thread -> Need to synchronize them?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Following code to create tasks from a big list which is split into sub lists (List l):

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpu);
        KwArrayDuration duration = new KwArrayDuration();
        for (List<Item> l : partition) {
            Runnable readingTask = new MainReadingTask(l, duration);
            executor.execute(readingTask);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // Execute all Threads
        }
```

Sample code of a worker thread:

```
public class MainReadingTask implements Runnable {

private KwArrayDuration duration;
private List<Item> wis;

    public MainReadingTask(List<Item> wis, KwArrayDuration duration) {
       this.wis = wis;
       this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
      for (Item wi : wis) {
        duration.setValueFromItem(wi.getId(), null, cal);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }

}
```

The object of the class `KwArrayDuration` is used by all threads as a `storage` class which inserts results from each task in a array list (`kwContentArray`).

Furthermore the class `KwArrayDuration` contains some methods to calc some stuff. These methods are invoked by each worker thread:

```
public synchronized void setValueFromItem(String id, DurationTime duration, Calendar cal) {
   if(duration != null) {
    try {
       this.setDurationValues(id, duration, cal);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   } else {
    int currentDay = getCurrentCalendarDay(cal);
    long time = 0;
    for (int i = currentDay; i < kwContentArray.size(); i++) {
       KwArrayWrapper currentDayKW = kwContentArray.get(i);
       currentDayKW.setValues(wi, String.valueOf(time));
       kwContentArray.set(i, currentDayKW);
    }
   }
}
```

**Question:**

Is it really needed to sync `setValueFromItem` function from shared `KwArrayDuration` instance? 
I think yes because results can differ if the scheduler stops e.g. after this line

```
int currentDay = getCurrentCalendarDay(cal);
```

and another thread uses this int value for further logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons you need to `synchronize`

1. If duration is mutable and shared or if cal is shared between other threads, then invoking `getCurrentCalendarDay(cal)` can result in different results then what was expected upon entering the method.  This also applies for `duration` if it is mutable & shared.
2. If `kwContentArray` is shared you also need to synchronize.

Moral of the story, is synchronize access to all shared mutable data.

Comment: Okay..."cal" is created in constructor of each thread like this: GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); Still needed to synchronize?

Comment: If cal is able to be accessed and modified by more than one thread at a time, then yes. Not the field cal, but cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 10).  Since cal is mutable you run into a data race via setters

Comment: Hmm, okay...I will create a new question because your answer does not answer my question in all details. I will accept your answer anyway and create more understandable code.